# How to retrieve Google Places Autocomplete API suggestions without commas between Google Places Types?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

Hi I am using bootstrap tokenfield to add more than one Google Places suggestions from Google Places Autocomplete API.

The token field uses comma as a separator. I just wanted to know if the suggestions can be retrieved without commas in the addresses.

It can be done for the places API as answered here:-
[Remove commas between google places types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255683/remove-commas-between-google-places-types)

But can it also be done for the Places Autocomplete API?

Comment: I don't see why not have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done also for the Google Places Autocomplete API. You're getting the same data retrieved